# Frequency response of output capacitance in an operational stage

Tags: capacitor, amplifier, analog, filter

Simulating the circuit shown below:
[image]

I found that the output capacitor C3 actually change the shape of the bode Diagram..

look at that:

With C3:

[image: With the capacitor C3 insert]

Without C3:

[image: Without the capacitor C3]

My question is how can I calculate the effect of C3 on the frequency resposnse of my circuit?

Answer (score 1):

In the real world, adding C3 will make the op-amp run closer to the point of instability and pushing it too far can lead to the opamp becoming an oscillator. Certainly, before oscilation begins, you will see overshoot on the output for a transient input change and therefore purposefully adding capacitance directly to the output of an opamp is generally seen as a bad thing to do.

A lot of opamps will give you some idea (in their respective data sheets) how much capacitance can be tolerated before things get out of control.

Regarding your circuit using the opamp called OPAMP_3T_VIRTUAL, it is unclear why this device is showing the change in response indicated in your diagrams but somewhere, inside the model parameters, there will be the open-loop output resistance value and this is likely to be factored in to any calculation you would wish to make.

As far as I'm concerned, nobody adds capacitance to an op-amp output with the hope of achieving anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

OpAmp datasheets often provide the Rout parameter.

In a feedback system, this becomes INDUCTIVE. The external capacitor. will resonate, and as Andy explained you'll see peaking and/or oscillation.

[image]

Can we predict the frequency of oscillation, given Rout?

This opamp has Rout of 100 ohms; the UGBW is 1MHz; we'll assume at 1MHz, the Zout is 100Ohms with a 90 degree phase shift; an inductor with 100 Ohms Z at 1MHz is a 16 uH inductor. And the Fresonate of 1uF and 16uH is about 40KKHz.